# How to keep running my Countdown after a refresh?

Tags: javascript, countdown, page-refresh, session-storage

I'm learning JS and I'm stuck...
I want to create a countdown (it's done, my countdown is working) who keep running when the page is reloaded. 
I used the sessionStorage to "save" the countdown value and also to check if a sessionStorage exists when the page is loaded.
The problem is, I don't know how keep running the countdown with values saved in the sessionStorage.

Could you please help me?

```js
class Timer {

    constructor(secondes, minutes) {
        this.secondes = secondes;
        this.minutes = minutes;
        this.button = document.getElementById("button");
        this.counter = document.getElementById("counter");
        this.storageCheck();
    }

    countdown(minutes) {
        var seconds = this.secondes;
        var mins = this.minutes; 
        var myCounter = this.counter; 
        function tick() {
            var current_minutes = mins-1;
            seconds--;
            myCounter.innerHTML = current_minutes + ":" + (seconds < 10 ? "0" : "") + seconds;
            var duration = sessionStorage.setItem("timer", myCounter.innerHTML);

        if( seconds > 0 ) {
                setTimeout(tick, 1000);
            } else {
                if(mins > 1){
                    countdown(mins-1);           
                }
            }
        }
      tick();
    }

    buttonClick() {
        button.addEventListener("click", () => {
            this.countdown(this.minutes);
        })
    }

    storageCheck() {
        if (sessionStorage.getItem("timer")) {
            // keep the countdown running
        }
    }
}

let newTimer = new Timer(60, 20);
newTimer.buttonClick();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Test Countdown</title>
</head>
<body>

 <div id="counter"></div>
 <button id="button">Run</button>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="countdown.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Change let newTimer = new Timer(60, 20); to get values from localStorage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In constructor before initializing secondes and minutes check if they are in the storage.If they dont exists then only set the `this.secondes = secondes` and `this.minutes = minutes;`

```
   constructor(secondes, minutes) {
        this.button = document.getElementById("button");
        this.counter = document.getElementById("counter");
        if(!this.storageCheck()){ //check if seconds are mins are stored in storage
            this.secondes = secondes; //if not set mins and sec to value passed in constructor
            this.minutes = minutes;
        }
        else{
          this.countdown(this.minutes);
        }


    }
```

In storage check function , check if the values are there, if there get the values and set to this.secondes and this.minutes and return true else return false

```
  storageCheck() {
        //if both mins and secs exists
        if (sessionStorage.getItem("mins") &&sessionStorage.getItem("secs")) {
            // keep the countdown running
            this.minutes=parseInt(sessionStorage.getItem("mins"));//get min
            this.secondes=parseInt(sessionStorage.getItem("secs"));//get secs
            return true;
        }
        else
          return false;
    }
```

and in countdown funciton save the values to storage

```
sessionStorage.setItem("mins",vm.minutes);//set current min
            sessionStorage.setItem("secs",vm.secondes);//set current sec
```

Try running this here :https://jsbin.com/bavexigute/1/edit?html,js,console,output

```
  class Timer {

    constructor(secondes, minutes) {
      this.button = document.getElementById("button");
      this.counter = document.getElementById("counter");
      if(!this.storageCheck()){ //check if seconds are mins are stored in storage
        this.secondes = secondes; //if not set mins and sec to value passed in constructor
        this.minutes = minutes;
       }
       else{
      this.countdown();
      }
    }

     countdown() {

       debugger;
       var vm=this;
        if(!(this.minutes-1<0))
           this.minutes--;
       let tick= function(){

           vm.secondes--
           if(vm.secondes==0){
              vm.secondes=59;
              vm.minutes--;
           }
           vm.counter.innerHTML =  vm.minutes + ":" + (vm.secondes < 10 ? "0" : "") + vm.secondes;
           if(vm.minutes == 0 && vm.secondes-1==0){
            vm.secondes--; 
            vm.counter.innerHTML =  vm.minutes + ":" + vm.secondes-1;

            }    
           else{
             setTimeout(tick,1000);
           }
           sessionStorage.setItem("mins",vm.minutes);//set current min
           sessionStorage.setItem("secs", vm.secondes);//set current sec
         }
        setTimeout(tick,1000);
     }    



    buttonClick() {
        button.addEventListener("click", () => {
            this.countdown();
        })
    }

    storageCheck() {
        //if both mins and secs exists
        if (sessionStorage.getItem("mins") && sessionStorage.getItem("secs")) {
            // keep the countdown running
            this.minutes=parseInt(sessionStorage.getItem("mins"));//get min
            this.secondes=parseInt(sessionStorage.getItem("secs"));//get secs
            return true;
        }
        else
          return false;
    }

}

let newTimer = new Timer(60, 20);
newTimer.buttonClick();
```

Comment: Wow thank you so much!! I learn a lot from your code :)
Last thing, when the page is reloaded, the countdown have to keep running without using the button "run". 
Any thoughts?

Comment: if storageCheck returns true call this.countdown(this.minutes); got it?

Comment: Not really... I mean it seems logical but not for my beginner brain :D
I don't know where to write it.

Comment: Hey, I made a mistake, It's not working well...
There is an error when seconds = 0.

Comment: i have a solution for that...but if i say that you wont learn that much...try doing it haha:)

Comment: Maybe just tell me a clue and if I can't find by myself after that, I'll ask for your help one more time :)

Comment: Hey @Ben ive updated the answer along with working jsbin

Comment: Ok now I can understand the process! 
Last thing, it goes from 01 sec to 59 sec with no 0..

==> Edit : I think it's okay, I changed if(vm.secondes == 0) to if(vm.secondes == -1)
Is that clean?

Answer (score 0):

You could use your storage check function to override the minutes and seconds arguments if it exists.

```js
constructor(mins, secs) {
  this.mins = mins
  this.secs = secs
  this.checkStorage = this.checkStorage.bind(this)
  this.checkStorage(mins, secs)
}
checkStorage(mins, secs) {
  if(window.storage) { // or whatever
    this.secs = window.storage.secs
    this.mins = window.storage.mins
  }
}
```

Something along those lines. Basically just have the setStorage function change the values that have been set in the constructor.

Comment: Thank you for your help!
But I don't understand how to do...
Do you have more informations about that?

Answer (score 0):

You can do a simple trick by doing this

```
window.onload = function() {
  let minutes = sessionStorage.getItem("minutes")
  let seconds = sessionStorage.getItem("seconds")
  let newTimer = new Timer(seconds, minutes);
};
```

And in sessionStorage instead of storing the whole innerHtml store minutes and seconds hopefully it will solve your problem